# Send IP from Server to Client. Java Network

Tags: java, sockets, networking, server, client

My goal here is to create a server-client program that sends the IP-number of the server & let the clients to connect to the IP-number (server).
See it like this way, I have a raspberry pi that is the server and its IP should be send to many computers which are the clients.
I have tried out some finished "multi-chat-server-client" code and other codes that connects the server to the client, but the question is, how do the client find the server?

This is what I'm trying to do:
 1. The server listens to a specific port, ex: port 3000.
 2. The clients should send out a message or different IP-numbers (192.168.1.0-255) to that port.
 3. When the message or the IP is correct with what the server is listening to, then the server should send its IP back to the clients.

In other words, we will not hard-code any IP on server side, the IP will change every-time the server restarts and so on, so the program should let the client send out IPs out to a port until the IP is correct with whatever IP the server is, then connect both.

Here are some code I have written and tried but Its not what I'm trying to do.
If you have some sites, tutorials, places to look at, let me know, I dont need any finished code, just want to understand how the Client can find the Server b sending out IPs until it connects.

This is also a link I have been looking at, but haven't found what I'm trying to do. http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

That you so much.

Server:

```
public class SocketServer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SocketClient ip = new SocketClient();

    System.out.println("Server started.");
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3000);
    System.out.println("Server is waiting for client...");
    Socket s = ss.accept();

    System.out.println("Client connected.");
    ip.getIpNumber();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String str = br.readLine();

    System.out.println("Client sent: " + str);

}
}
```

Client:

```
public class SocketClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 3000;
    Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Send message to server...");
    String str = scn.next();

    OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os);
    out.println(str);
    out.flush();
}

public void getIpNumber() {

    try {
        String ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("Clients ip number is: " + ip);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

EDIT 1:
I did create MultiCast Sender & Receiver, here is the code.

Multicast Sender:

```
public class MulticastSender {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1");
        MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket();
        String ipMessage = "Multimessage";
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(ipMessage.getBytes(), ipMessage.length(), group, 3000);
        multicastSocket.send(datagramPacket);
        multicastSocket.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Multicast Receiver:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1");
        MulticastSocket multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(3000);
        multicastSocket.joinGroup(group);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        multicastSocket.receive(datagramPacket);
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
        multicastSocket.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

EDIT 2:

With help from Ipper and the link to Michiel De Mey's site, this is what I took from it and it works, but IF I have edited in wrong way or something, let me know.

Server:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

DatagramSocket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread discoveryThread = new Thread(Server.getInstance());
    discoveryThread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        //Keep a socket open to listen to all the UDP traffic that is destined for this port
        socket = new DatagramSocket(3000, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
        socket.setBroadcast(true);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Ready to receive broadcast packets!");

            //Receive a packet
            byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);

            //Packet received
            System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Discovery packet received from: " + packet.getAddress().getHostAddress());
            System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Packet received; data: " + new String(packet.getData()));

            //See if the packet holds the right command (message)
            String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
            if (message.equals("DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_REQUEST")) {
                byte[] sendData = "DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_RESPONSE".getBytes();

                //Send a response
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, packet.getAddress(), packet.getPort());
                socket.send(sendPacket);

                System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Sent packet to: " + sendPacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static Server getInstance() {
    return DiscoveryThreadHolder.INSTANCE;
}

private static class DiscoveryThreadHolder {

    private static final Server INSTANCE = new Server();
}
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Client client = new Client();
    client.connect();

}

public void connect() {

    try {
        DatagramSocket c;
        c = new DatagramSocket();
        c.setBroadcast(true);
        byte[] sendData = "DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_REQUEST".getBytes();

        try {

            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ip, 3000);
            c.send(packet);
            System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Request packet sent to: 255.255.255.255 (DEFAULT)");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        // Broadcast the message over all the network interfaces
        Enumeration interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = (NetworkInterface) interfaces.nextElement();

            if (networkInterface.isLoopback() || !networkInterface.isUp()) {
                continue; // Don't want to broadcast to the loopback interface
            }

            for (InterfaceAddress interfaceAddress : networkInterface.getInterfaceAddresses()) {
                InetAddress broadcast = interfaceAddress.getBroadcast();
                if (broadcast == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Send the broadcast package!
                try {
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, broadcast, 3000);
                    c.send(sendPacket);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

                System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Request packet sent to: " + broadcast.getHostAddress());
            }
        }

        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Done looping over all network interfaces. Now waiting for a reply!");

        //Wait for a response
        byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
        c.receive(receivePacket);

        //We have a response
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Broadcast response from server: " + receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());

        //Check if the message is correct
        String message = new String(receivePacket.getData()).trim();
        if (message.equals("DISCOVER_FUIFSERVER_RESPONSE")) {
            //DO SOMETHING WITH THE SERVER'S IP (for example, store it in your controller)
            System.out.println("Server's IP: " + receivePacket.getAddress());
        }

        //Close the port!
        c.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: The client initiates the connection and thus can tell whether a connection could be made to which ip. There is no need to let the server tell the client its ip. Perhaps some sort of handshake is required to verify your client is connecting to a proper server instance.

Comment: You might also consider using UDP for discovery instead of TCP... see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: Hey ipper. I wrote some Multicast receiver & sender code, did edit and updated the original post, but once again, with the multicast.. its UDP, not TCP and still hardcoded address (224.x.x.x). The question is that if the ip changes or the udp is blocked then this would not work.. am I right? Iam very new to network. How do the client know how to connect to the server? It must send out something and hope for Server to answer... right?

Comment: you can go two ways... or maybe combine two strategies. When a client comes up it will be broadcast messages asking for a server to reply with its ip etc. Or you can have the server broadcast its ip when it comes up. Combining the two would make it robust.
But when a network blocks this (UDP) message this of course would not work.

Comment: Hey ipper. You wrote "When a client comes up it will be broadcast messages asking for a server to reply with its ip etc."
This is exactly what I asked for, but how would I do to make that work?
In other words, client should send out ip from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255 and compare its number with the server to connect.
Think like 2 seperated programs that run, how do Client know anything about the server it is searching for, if not just sending out ip numbers ranged from x to y.
You have any tutorial or site that shows how client can send out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should provide what you need (if you want to write the code yourself):

http://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/

You might also want to consider using a library such as

- https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns
- http://jslp.sourceforge.net/jSLP/userguide.html

Comment: Thank you once again ipper. Talked to the guys who gave me this to do and they said this:       
1. Server has a port AND the IP.
2. Client sends out message to that port until it finds the server ip.

Example: Server has IP 192.168.1.x and runs on port 3000.
Client will run on port 3000 but it will start send message from 192.168.1.1 until x.x.x.255.  Every example I have seen, they put "String ip = "localhost"" on the client side which is wrong in my project, because the job is for client to find the server IP, thanks again, will look at the links and see if it helps me :)

Comment: The Michael Demey site and his code is exactly what I was looking for, but his code wont work at all, so much errors and things he dont talk about. He call a class Controller_Base but there are no such thing is his code, its a lot of errors, but thanks, I will read more about UDP broadcasting and try to fins the IP that way :)